# How do you define the inverse of an (exponential Lie) operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I know this is a fairly general question, but I would like to know anything I can about obtaining the inverse of an exponential of a lie operator. More specifically, I want to know how one can constructively define the following operators:

$$\frac{1}{e^A},~~~\frac{1}{1+e^{A_1}+e^{A_2}+\cdots}, ~~~ \frac{1}{f(e^{A_i})}$$

where $A_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots$ are Lie operators.

---

**EDIT:**

@avs pointed out in his original answer what exactly those inverse operators are (i.e. how one can define them) but in a non-constructive way. I am specifically looking for ways of constructing representations of those inverse operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, if we have any linear operator $A$ for which the exponential $\exp(A)$ is meaningful, then $A$ commutes with $-A$, and so
$$
\exp(A) \exp(-A) = \exp(A + (-A)) = \exp(\mbox{the zero operator}) = I.
$$

The inverse of $(I + B)^{-1}$ (again, if the latter is defined) is $(I+B)$.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but it isn't constructive. I'll edit the question to call for specifically constructive answers.

Comment: Not sure how the first part of my answer fails to be constructive.  If we are given an $A$ and would like to invert $\exp(A)$, how is the formula $\exp(-A)$ not constructive?

As for inverting any invertible operator $B$, at least formally (without worrying about norms and convergence), write $B = I - (I-B)$ and use the geometric series formula
$$
{1 \over x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots.
$$

Comment: (1) I think you meant for the denominator to be $(1-x)$ in your geometric series formula. (2) How would you know whether or not such a geometric series would converge for operators?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The webpage doesn't let me edit it any more.  As for convergence, it has to be ascertained on a case by case basis, for the specific operators at hand.  (Generally, one looks at their norms.)